# unresolved symbols while linking boost program options

Tags: c++, cmake, boost-program-options

A user of my project reported this error to me. I cannot reproduce it on my computer or my lab's server, so I ask it here.

The project uses CMake to generate build environment. It uses the FindBoost utility (provided with CMake) to find Boost resources.

On the beginning, my user said while linking the final programs, the compiler was provided with "/usr/lib64/lib64/libboost_XXX.so", instead of the correct "/usr/lib64/libboost_XXX.so". I failed to find why CMake generated such weird library location, and asked him to manually set the variable **Boost_LIBRARIES**, and print them:

```
Boost libraries are: /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so;/usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so;/usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so
```

Things seem to be correct. The compilation was successful. But when it goes to linking, the program cries about many undefined symbols:

```
CMakeFiles/ht-filter.dir/ht-filter.cpp.o: In function `parse_options(int, char**)':
/public/home/yli/Downloads/htqc-0.15.0-Source/ht-filter.cpp:43: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
......
/usr/local/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:372: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
```

This is the two typical of the so-many errors: one locates from my source code, the other locates from boost's header. In the corresponding line of my source code, I just created the  options_description object

```
// I renamed boost::program_options to opt
opt::options_description opt_main("Options:");
```

The OS of my user is CentOS 6.2, and his Boost version is 1.50.0 which is similiar with the one in my computer. The version of CMake of my user is 2.8.11 which is also same with mine.

Comment: Maybe your user has 2 versions of boost installed, or 1 version and some "residual" of another version?

Answer (score 2):

While using CMake's find_package for Boost, you can give a few hints to CMake which may help it find the correct library, such as:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr")

find_package(Boost 1.50.0)

message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
```

Also if you are linking with dynamic libs make sure to let Boost headers know about it (I think you shouldn't mess with the order in here):

```
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK )
```